# EmailJS for multiple step React Form

Tags: reactjs

I have a multiple step React Form and when I sent up the EmailJS, only the last step of the form gets sent to Email. I want all the pages from the first step to the last step to be sent to the email. How can I solve this?

I set up emailJS correctly so email does get sent but not the whole form. I'm storing input data using react hook but I'm not sure how to fire up the event for the sendEmail function.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Form.css';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';

export default function Form(){

    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        name: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
        shippingAddress: "",
        projectAddress: "",

        customDesign: "",
        description: "",
        image: "",
        dimensionDetails: "",
        manufactureDetails: "",

        designText: "",
        deadline: "",
        budget: "",
        comment: ""
    })

    const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

    const updateForm = (e) => {
        setForm ({
            ...form,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        })
        console.log(e.target)
    }

    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        emailjs.sendForm(
            'service_z3p8h0m', 
            'template_svmf3nm', 
            e.target, 
            'user_7Pf1rN0FgZQwrrMpFSw55'
        )
          .then((result) => {
              console.log(result.text, e.target, e.name);
          }, (error) => {
              console.log(error.text);
          });
        //   e.target.reset();
    }
    



    return (
        <div className = "form-box">

            <h5 className = "form-step"> steps: {count} of 4 </h5>

            <form onSubmit = { sendEmail }>

            {/* //     (e) => alert(`
            // submitted 
            // 1${form.name}
            // 2${form.phone}
            // 3${form.email}
            // 4${form.shippingAddress}
            // 5${form.projectAddress}
    
            // 6${form.customDesign}
            // 7${form.description}
            // 8${form.image}
            // 9${form.dimensionDetails}
            // 10${form.manufactureDetails}
    
            // 11${form.designText}
            // 12${form.deadline}
            // 13${form.budget}
            // 14${form.comment}
            // `) */}

                {count === 1  ?  (  //when the page count is 1 show this 
                <div className = "field1">
                <label> customer info </label>
            
                <input 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="name" 
                    placeholder="Name"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.name}
                />

                
                <input 
                    type ="tel" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="phone" 
                    placeholder="Phone 000-000-0000"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.phone}
                />

                <input 
                    type ="email" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="email" 
                    placeholder="E-mail"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.email}
                />

                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="shippingAddress" 
                    placeholder="Shipping Address"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.shippingAddress}
                />

                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="projectAddress" 
                    placeholder="Physical location of the project"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.projectAddress}
                />
                </div>
                ):null} {/* if the page count is not equal to 1 then null */}

                {count === 2  ?  (
                <div className = "field2">
                <label> project description </label>

                
                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="customDesign"
                    placeholder="Are you interested in a custom design, or do you already have a design to work from?" 
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.customDesign}
                />

                
                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="description" 
                    placeholder="Briefly describe the project and your brand, if applicable"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.description}
                />

                Please upload the reference images, including your logo
                <input 
                    type ="file" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="image" 
                    placeholder="image"
                    
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.image}
                />
                </div>
                ):null} 

                {count === 3  ?  (
                <div className = "field3">
                <label> dimensional details </label>
                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="demensionDetail" 
                    placeholder="If the design will be painted directly onto a surface, such as a wall or vehicle, please provide dimensions and a description of the surface. Please include maximum working height from ground, and any other details related to access and conditions of the working area."
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.demensionDetail}
                />

                
                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="manufactureDetail" 
                    placeholder="If you are ordering a manufactured sign (wood, metal, canvas etc), please provide dimensions, whether the sign will be single or double-sided, and if you would like hanging hardware to be included."
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.manufactureDetail}
                />
                </div>
                ):null} 

                {count === 4  ?  (
                <div className = "field4">
                <label> more info </label>

 
                <input 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="designText" 
                    placeholder="Text in the design"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.designText}
                />

                <input 
                    type ="date" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="deadline" 
                    placeholder="Deadline"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.deadline}
                />

                <input 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="budget" 
                    placeholder="Budget"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.budget}
                />

                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="comment" 
                    placeholder="Comments"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.comment}
                />
                </div>
                ):null} 
                

                {/* SUBMIT button */}
                {count === 4  ?  (
                <button 
                type = "submit"
                id= "submitBtn"
                className = "submitBtn"
                > submit</button>
                ):null} 

            </form>
            {/* end of form */}


            {/* PREV button */}
            <button 
                className = "prevBtn"
                type = "submit" 
                onClick = {() => setCount(count -1)} //decrease the page count
                disabled = {count <= 1} //don't do anytying when the page is the first page
            > PREV </button>

            {/* NEXT button */}
            <button 
                className = "nextBtn"
                type = "submit" 
                onClick = {() => setCount(count +1)}
                disabled = {count >= 4} //at the last page, disable the next button
            > NEXT </button>

        </div>
        // end of form-box
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the conditional logic (`count === current_step? (show fields): null`), it will remove the inputs in the steps from the DOM. That's why it sends the only inputs from last step. You can use css `visivility` to hide the form inputs from previous steps and it will still in the DOM. Try below,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Form.css';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';

export default function Form(){

    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        name: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
        shippingAddress: "",
        projectAddress: "",

        customDesign: "",
        description: "",
        image: "",
        dimensionDetails: "",
        manufactureDetails: "",

        designText: "",
        deadline: "",
        budget: "",
        comment: ""
    })

    const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

    const updateForm = (e) => {
        setForm ({
            ...form,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        })
        console.log(e.target)
        console.log(form)
    }

    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        emailjs.sendForm(
            'service_z3p8h0m', 
            'template_svmf3nm', 
            '#myEmailForm',
            'user_7Pf1rN0FgZQwrrMpFSw55'
        )
          .then((result) => {
              console.log(
                  result.text
                  );
          }, (error) => {
              console.log(error.text);
          });
        e.target.reset();
    }



    return (
        <div className = "form-box">

            <h5 className = "form-step"> steps: {count} of 4 </h5>

            <form onSubmit = { sendEmail } id='myEmailForm' >


                <div className = "field1" style={{ visibility: count === 1 ? 'unset' : 'hidden' }}>
                <label> customer info </label>
            
                <input 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="name" 
                    placeholder="Name"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.name}
                />

                
                <input 
                    type ="tel" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="phone" 
                    placeholder="Phone 000-000-0000"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.phone}
                />

                <input 
                    type ="email" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="email" 
                    placeholder="E-mail"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.email}
                />

                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="shippingAddress" 
                    placeholder="Shipping Address"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.shippingAddress}
                />

                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="projectAddress" 
                    placeholder="Physical location of the project"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.projectAddress}
                />
                </div>

                <div className = "field2" style={{ visibility: count === 2 ? 'unset' : 'hidden' }}>
                <label> project description </label>

                
                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="customDesign"
                    placeholder="Are you interested in a custom design, or do you already have a design to work from?" 
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.customDesign}
                />

                
                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="description" 
                    placeholder="Briefly describe the project and your brand, if applicable"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.description}
                />

                Please upload the reference images, including your logo
                <input 
                    type ="file" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="image" 
                    placeholder="image"
                    
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.image}
                />
                </div>

                <div className = "field3" style={{ visibility: count === 3 ? 'unset' : 'hidden' }}>
                <label> dimensional details </label>
                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="demensionDetail" 
                    placeholder="If the design will be painted directly onto a surface, such as a wall or vehicle, please provide dimensions and a description of the surface. Please include maximum working height from ground, and any other details related to access and conditions of the working area."
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.demensionDetail}
                />

                
                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="manufactureDetail" 
                    placeholder="If you are ordering a manufactured sign (wood, metal, canvas etc), please provide dimensions, whether the sign will be single or double-sided, and if you would like hanging hardware to be included."
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.manufactureDetail}
                />
                </div>

                <div className = "field4" style={{ visibility: count === 4 ? 'unset' : 'hidden' }}>
                <label> more info </label>

 
                <input 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="designText" 
                    placeholder="Text in the design"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.designText}
                />

                <input 
                    type ="date" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="deadline" 
                    placeholder="Deadline"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.deadline}
                />

                <input 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="budget" 
                    placeholder="Budget"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.budget}
                />

                <textarea 
                    type ="text" 
                    className = "form-input"
                    name ="comment" 
                    placeholder="Comments"
                    onChange ={updateForm} 
                    value = {form.comment}
                />
                </div>

                {/* SUBMIT button */}
                {count === 4  ?  (
                <button 
                type = "submit"
                id= "submitBtn"
                className = "submitBtn"
                > submit</button>
                ):null} 

            </form>
            {/* end of form */}


            {/* PREV button */}
            <button 
                className = "prevBtn"
                type = "submit" 
                onClick = {() => setCount(count -1)} //decrease the page count
                disabled = {count <= 1} //don't do anytying when the page is the first page
            > PREV </button>

            {/* NEXT button */}
            <button 
                className = "nextBtn"
                type = "submit" 
                onClick = {() => setCount(count +1)}
                disabled = {count >= 4} //at the last page, disable the next button
            > NEXT </button>

        </div>
        // end of form-box
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amila. This makes sense!

Comment: @GreemJellyfish, if this solved your issue, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Amila so I actually tried different way to solve this problem. Earlier you said that using REST API `send` function and using `form` would work https://www.emailjs.com/docs/rest-api/send/ You mentioned about it and my mentor guided me that the rest api send function will work so I tried and it worked!! So I didn't get to play with the CSS visibility yet.

Comment: thank you! I just tested your solution.  '#myEmailForm' needs to be `e.target` this time. Thanks again! I mentioned about all your suggestions on my blog and checked your solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your `form` instead of `e.target` to send the whole form as a `JSON`. See below,

```
    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        emailjs.sendForm(
            'service_z3p8h0m', 
            'template_svmf3nm', 
             form,  //e.target, 
            'user_7Pf1rN0FgZQwrrMpFSw55'
        )
          .then((result) => {
              console.log(result.text, e.target, e.name);
          }, (error) => {
              console.log(error.text);
          });
        //   e.target.reset();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Amila! I changed `e.target` to `form` but now the email isn't even sending. I think it's because `e.target` has different structure from `form`. When I console.log `e.target` I get this

Comment: `e.target` 
```
<form class = "emailjs-success">
<div className = "field4">
<label> more info </label>
 
<input 
    type ="text" 
    className = "form-input"
    name ="designText" 
    placeholder="Text in the design"
    value ="hello world"
/>

</form>
```

Comment: `form` ```{name: "john doe", phone: "", email: "", shippingAddress: "", projectAddress: "", …}
budget: ""
comment: ""
customDesign: ""
deadline: "2021-04-11"
description: ""
designText: "hello world"
dimensionDetails: ""
email: ""
image: ""
manufactureDetails: ""
name: "john doe"
phone: ""
projectAddress: ""
shippingAddress: "" ```

Comment: so `form` is in key value pair format and `e.target` is in html form. How can I send the form info as html format then?

Comment: @Greem Jellyfish, you need to add a querySelector as the third param. replace `e.target` with `'#myEmailForm'`. Then add this id to the form like this => `<form onSubmit = { sendEmail } id='myEmailForm'>`

Comment: my first solution would work, if you use `send` function instead of `sendForm` function.

Comment: Thank you @amilia. I added a new querySelector as a third param but it's still only sending the last step inputs.

Comment: ```    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        emailjs.sendForm(
            'service_z3p8h0m', 
            'template_svmf3nm', 
            '#myEmailForm',
            'user_7Pf1rN0FgZQwrrMpFSw55'
        )
          .then((result) => {
              console.log(
                  result.text
                  );
          }, (error) => {
              console.log(error.text);
          });
        e.target.reset();
    }



    return (
            <form onSubmit = { sendEmail } id='myEmailForm' >

Comment: So only `<div className = "field4">` gets send but not all other field1, field2, field3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option to solve this problem by using REST API `send` function.

I wrote [a blog](https://greemjellyfish.medium.com/emailjs-how-to-connect-a-multiple-step-react-form-to-emailjs-a183699e7d3d) about how I solved this problem and came up with the working solutions.

[EmailJS has REST API doc](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/rest-api/send/) but it's listed in Jquery so you have to change it to vanila JS for the react file. You can refer to this [mozilla JSON POST fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) document.

```
//"send" method using fetch
    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            service_id: 'service_z3p8h0m',
            template_id: 'template_svmf3nm',
            user_id: 'user_7Pf1rN0FgZQwrrMpFSw55',
            template_params: form
        };
    
        fetch('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.statusText);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });
        
        e.target.reset();
    }
```